# No method with correct signature type found in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add hyperlink in my Xamarin Forms and I get this error:

**No method Handle_Tapped with correct signature found on type App.Greet**

My xaml code:

```
 <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap">
   <Label.FormattedText>
     <FormattedString>
       <Span Text="Google">
         <Span.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Handle_Tapped" />
         <Span.GestureRecognizers>
       </Span>
      </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
 </Label>
```

.cs file:

```
public async void Handle_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String url = "www.google.com";
        await Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri(url), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can use the `async` keyword

Comment: Your code works fine on my android emulator . What is the version of XF in your project?And did you debug it on iOS or Android ?

Comment: I restarted my visual studio without changing any code, and everything works fine now.

Comment: Type your answer in to the solution below so we can mark this question answered

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I restarted  visual studio without changing any code, and there is no error now

Comment: Just a comment to this if the event was created while the code is being debugged it will also give an error and work even the debug is stopped this is due to code being compiled and not having the updated code-behind code.